# What is the first argument to eslint "indent" rule

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have a simple config on the project that uses eslit

```
"rules": {
    "indent": [2, 2, {"SwitchCase": 1}]
}
```

According to documentation, second '2' is for number of spaces used for indent (can be set to 4 or 6 or "tab").
What about the first '2'?
[Old documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/1.0.0/rules/indent) uses '2' here while [New documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent) uses "error"

```
"indent": ["error", "tab"]
```

Both say nothing about it. What is it for?

Comment: The first item in the array is always the rule severity (number or string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [the general documentation for configuring rules](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules):

> - "off" or 0 - turn the rule off
> - "warn" or 1 - turn the rule on as a warning (doesn’t affect exit code)
> - "error" or 2 - turn the rule on as an error (exit code is 1 when triggered)

2 is the same as "error".

Comment: That's what happens, when you are in a hurry and don't read the documentation from start. Lucky, you guys are always here to help, thank you, solved.

Answer (score 0):

I found a reference on the github repository: https://github.com/eslint/eslint#configuration

> "off" or 0 - turn the rule off
>
> "warn" or 1 - turn the rule on as a warning (doesn't affect exit code)
>
> "error" or 2 - turn the rule on as an error (exit code will be 1)

This explain all options for the first param.